# Magento, Magic Zoom and Magic 360

Tags: product, template

I have implemented Magic ToolBox's Magic Zoom and Magic 360 viewers into my product pages.  I was wondering though how I can designate for the Zoom viewer to be the default viewer that initially comes up when the page is loaded.  Currently the 360 viewer is the one that initially loads for the product and I do not see anything within Magento Enterprise for this to be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do by editing the media.phtml file located here:

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/magiczoomplus/media.phtml

1. Check that you are using the latest version of the [Magento module for Magic 360](http://www.magictoolbox.com/magic360/modules/magento/) - it is frequently updated.
2. Locate the media.phtml file on your server by FTP. Download it and replace this code:

   ```
   $main = '<div id="mainImageContainer">'.$main.'</div>'.
   '<div id="magic360Container" style="display: none;">'.$magic360Tool->getMainTemplate($_magic360Images, array("id" => "productMagic360")).'</div>';
   ```

   with the following code:

   ```
   $main = '<div id="mainImageContainer" style="display: none;">'.$main.'</div>'.
   '<div id="magic360Container">'.$magic360Tool->getMainTemplate($_magic360Images, array("id" => "productMagic360")).'</div>';
   ```
3. Save and upload the edited file to your server (we recommend making a backup first).

If you would like the Magic Toolbox support team to edit the media.phtml file for you, send the URL of your store to them via the contact form on the Magic Toolbox website.